# Copy duplicates of selected names

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a database that has many duplicates. If I select any name in a particular cell, the data related with that name should be exported to a new worksheet in the same workbook. For example, if there is a name `Amol` repeated 5 times, `Geet` 9 times, `Devidas` 11 times and so on, if I write `Devidas` in a cell, the data related with `Devidas` from all 11 lines should be exported to a new worksheet. I need to do this using ***formula*** alone and not ***VBA***. Any help that will point to a solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: Google "Paste Values in Excel"

Comment: Sir, Offcourse, It is done with Filter then copy and paste but I need formula to make it automatically..............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not provide sufficient data and position of data in your sheet. Also lacking of how many column do you have. Which column do you want to return in sheet2? Whatever, assuming your data in `Sheet1` and you want to put filtered in in `Sheet2`. So, use following formula to `sheet2` to filter data related `Devidas`.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$21,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$21="Devidas",ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$21),""),ROWS($A$1:$A1))),"")
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

You have to adjust formula for `Index()` function to return particular column. Let us know by comment if you feel any difficulties to apply the formula.

Comment: Sir, Formula I use not working.......of course, there may be my mistakes..........so should I send you excel file?.......In which I have properly explained.......pls tell me how should I send you that file.....?

Comment: Send it to `harun24hr@gmail.com`

Comment: Also explain very well what you want?

Comment: @user6177766 Check your mail. I have used same formula what I have posted here. Just made some adjustment to meet your requirement So, if it helps you, accept my answer (mark as green) and up-vote it.

Comment: Perfect!   Solved! 100%

Comment: So finally the formula was in second sheet `ABC` cell 'A5' `{=IFERROR(INDEX(LIC!$A$5:$H$1000,SMALL(IF(LIC!$B$5:$B$1000=LIC!$I$1,ROW(LIC!$B$5:$B$1000)-ROW(LIC!$B$4),""),ROWS(LIC!$A$5:$A5)),COLUMN(A$4)),"")}`

Comment: Sir, One more issue, If I double click on the formula, the content become invisible.......so pls and second If I copy that formula to my sheet.....it's not working......so is there any suggestion for me.....

Comment: It is an array formula so, whenever you double click on cell or copy the formula then you have to press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` at same time.

Comment: Check this link out: [Array formulas for beginners](https://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/excel-array-formulas-for-beginners/)